# Hilbert symbol Definitons

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I found a definition of the quadratic *Hilbert Symbol* 
(the one with
$(a,b)=1$ if $ax^2+by^2=z^2$ for some $(x,y,z)≠(0,0,0)$ ) 
 for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_symbol) or [here.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HilbertSymbol.html)

I am now looking for a proof that this follows from the original definition of this Symbol by Hilbert.

Comment: Do you have a link to the original definition by Hilbert?

Comment: I just have a german version of it but i can try to translate https://share-your-photo.com/fade169c41/album

Comment: @Lisa: Please make this question self-contained and write out the original definition.

Answer (score 3):

We can simply rewrite Serre's definition $ax^2+by^2=z^2$ as
$$
ax^2=z^2-by^2={\rm Norm}_{K/k}(z+y\sqrt{b}),
$$
where $K=k(\sqrt{b})$ is now a quadratic field extension of $k$. This is exactly how the linked German text defines it.